# why the output of my code is zero?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class superclass { 
    superclass() {
        show();
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("three");
    }
}

class subclass extends superclass {
    int x=3;

    void show() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) { 
         subclass s=new subclass();
    }
}
```

Output:  `0`

According to me: first the subclass constructor gets executed, which then calls superclass constructor. This means that, first of all, the `show()` method of the superclass should execute and should print `three`, but that is not happening. Why?

Answer (score 4):

The superclass constructor is executed before any of the subclass variables are initialized.  So, the `x` in `subclass` is still `0` (the default value) while the `superclass` constructor is executing.  Polymorphism still works when a method is called in a constructor, so `subclass`'s `show` is called, printing `x` prints `0`.  This illustrates the danger in calling an overridable method in a constructor -- variables may not be initialized yet.  In this case, `x` isn't `3` [yet.

The [JLS, Section 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), covers the steps in executing a constructor.

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. **Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class**, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

(emphasis mine)

The variables are initialized after the call to the superclass constructor completes, whether that call is explicit or implicit.

Comment: this is the same link where I am learning from. But I didn't get why the subclass's show() is executing in superclass constructor?

Comment: As I've stated above, polymorphism is at work here.  The runtime type of `s` is `subclass`, so the `superclass` constructor is calling `subclass`'s `show` method.

Comment: but I have not called show() using object s

Comment: if I write `s.show()` , then I can understand why is it going to sublass `show()` , but here what is the relation between `s` type and the `superclass` constructor

Comment: When you create an object for `s`, it's a `subclass`.  There is no explicit constructor for that class, so the Java compiler creates an [implicit default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).  The default constructor calls the no-arg superclass constructor, which is `superclass()` here.  Your `superclass()` constructor explicitly calls `show()`.

Comment: and you said that `s` is `subclass` type that's why it is calling `subclass` `show`  . Ok, but the problem is still same if I write `superclass s=new subclass()` . now `s` is `superclass` type, but the output is still same

Comment: Yes, you've just demonstrated polymorphism.  The method called depends on the runtime type of the object on which the method is called, not the variable type.

Comment: means it depends on `new subclass()` ??

Comment: Yes.  Please see the [Java tutorial on polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

`subclass` overrides `superclass`'s `show` method. Therefore when you create an instance of `subclass`, `subclass`'s `show` method is executed.

The reason it returns `0` and not `3` is that it is called from the constructor of `superclass`, which is executed before the instance variables of `subclass` are initialized. Therefore `x` still contains a default value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

As i said last time you posted this question, when you make an object of `subclass`, it calls the `superclass` constructor which calls the child `show()` method (which overrides the super `show()` method) **before** x is initialized to 3.

If you had

```
subclass(){
   show();
}
```

in your subclass, then it would print `3` because that would call the show() method after x has been initialized to that value.

If you wanted to print `three` then you should call `super.show()` in the subclass constructor.

Comment: why is it overriding the superclass's show() ?

Comment: @PuspenderTanwar Because you made an object of the child class, so all of its methods override the super class' methods. If this helped, please choose an answer that helped the most

Comment: if I write `s.show()` , then I can understand why is it going to subclass `show()` , but here what is the relation between `s` type and the `superclass` constructor

Comment: @PuspenderTanwar When you make an object, with the syntax `A objectName = new A();` it calls the constructor of that class. If that class has no constructor (your subclass doesn't have one) it calls the _parent's_ constructor instead. But in the scope of the child class.

Comment: what is meant by "in scope of the child class"

Comment: @PuspenderTanwar what i mean by that is that since it's the child object that is invoking its parent constructor, all the children's methods are going to take priority (since its an object of the child). However, since the constructor is in the parent class, then the variables in the child class are only initialized after that constructor call.

Comment: @PuspenderTanwar personally, i suggest always specify a constructor. It makes your code less confusing and prevents unwanted behaviour. You should add a constructor to your child class.

Comment: ok, now I got the point. thankyou

Comment: @PuspenderTanwar no problem, remember, if you found an answer to be helpful, choose that answer as the solution, so those who are experiencing your problems can know which  is the most helpful.